# How to tail log from go app on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, logging, go, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to find how I can have my `fmt.Printf` or `log.Printf` from my go app being tail or logged like we are able to do for .NET or Node apps to the Application logs.

Based on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308005037/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)) by enabling the Application logging from the portal all stdout should be logged. But for some reasons my log output are not printed either when using the azure CLI or downloading the log. There's no Application directory in the LogFiles directory of the diagnostics.zip.

`azure site log tail sitename` or `azure site log download sitename`

In Node I use the `IISNode.yml` file to tell to log the `console.log` to the application log. Is there a similar way of doing this for go app?

```
loggingEnabled: true
devErrorsEnabled: true
```

Comment: Hi Dominic, I've removed the indirection by google, but I don't know if your question was specific to the old version of the article, or not. So I put two links. Feel free to [edit] and keep only the most relevant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven`t implement logging for Go application yet. Here is the pending work item in our repository https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1535

Feel free to raise your needs onto our Github issue, and we will triage and address it according to schedule.

As of now, you will need to handle your own logging.

Comment: Thanks  I will. But from what I thought the fact of enabling Application Logging in the portal was equivalent to saying grab standard stdout output and saving it to File or Blob or display it when using log tail? Why is this related to Kudu? Aren't Kudu there to deploy app from a git push action?

Comment: @DominicSt-Pierre Kudu is more than a deployment engine. and the logging is handling by our team as well (most of the code might not in Kudu)